# how to install openfire on cpanel (my domain)

Tags: xmpp, hosting, cpanel, openfire

I have installed openfire on my pc and I have spark client also .Its working fine when server/host : is localhost .

But How do I install the same on my domain www.example.com/test/  .I transferred the entire zip file and I did not find any set up/html/php file to run setup on my cpanel hosting folder.

How do I install openfire on my domain ? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you have ssh access to you domain ? if yes then you can do is easily

Comment: @HaiderAli Can you explain more in details Sir.I really appreciate it .Also can you suggest few links for the same.I have no clue to how to install on cpanel domain.There is not setup file also.

Comment: @jason did you get any working solution for this?

Comment: @user3606902 Try on aws!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using shared hosting (Cpanel) you need to have SSH access to your server. You can easily enable SSH for your shared hosting server. [How to enable SSH/Shell Access in cPanel](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/ssh_cpanel.htm) might help you to do so else use [Google](http://google.com) it.

**Installing and configuring open fire**

- Login to your server via SSH in terminal

  > ssh username_of_server@ip_adress_of_server
- Run in terminal

  > sudo apt-get update
  >   sudo apt-get upgrade
- Install JRE ( if you didn't have already because Openfire is in JAVA)

  > sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

Now you have enviornment of java and openfire. Following [tutorial](https://library.linode.com/communications/xmpp/openfire/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin) **Installing Openfire** heading onwards .......
I hope it helps you to kick off.

Comment: @Haider Ali cPanel is not working over Ubuntu so these command also will not work